# TypeError: this.list.push is not a function in ecmascript 6

Tags: javascript

When calling the add function of my GroceryList class, I get an error:

> TypeError: this.list.push is not a function

Why is this?

```
class GroceryList {

      constructor() {
        this.list = {
            value: [],
            writable: false,
            enumerable: true  
          };
      }

        add(item) {
        this.list.push(item);
      }

      getAll() {
        return this.list;
      }

      getItemIndex(value) {
        var index = this.list.length;
        while(--index > -1) {
          if(this.list[index] === value) {
            return index;
          }
        }
        return -1;
      }
    }
```

Comment: `this.list` is an object. Only arrays have a `push` method. That hasn't changed with ES6.

Comment: Yeah, you're declaring `list` as `{...}`.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing

- **A whole object**

vs

- **A list as an attribute of that object**

The `list` object contains a list, but that does **not** mean it is a list. You should write `list.value.push(x)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use a *property descriptor*. However, those descriptors only work with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

```
this.list = {
  value: [],
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true  
};
```

literally assigns an object with the properties `value`, `writable` and `enumerable` to `this.list`.

What you seem to want is:

```
Object.definProperty(this, 'list', {
  value: [],
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true  
});
```

Now `this.list` returns an array, but it's not possible to assign a new value to the property.